# How to utilise AZURE VM's drive data into an azure cloud hosted app

Tags: php, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I have an Azure virtual machine which has more than 30 GB of images in its drive. Also there is a mysql workbench database running on it.

I want to utilise this DB and images into my azure cloud hosted app(Web+MySQL).

My php web app pulls images from the folder present in the VM's drive and shows the corresponding record of that image from the Mysql workbench database also present in the VM. How can I do that?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking: Are you trying to share the drive itself (e.g. as a file share)? Are you trying to connect to the MySQL database engine running on your VM? Please edit your question to clarify. Right now it's unclear.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Hi David, sorry I was unclear about my question before. I have edited it now. Please have a look at it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot directly request for the image files in VMs from web application. But we can consider a workaround, which will leverage [Azure File Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share). You can store the image files into the shared folder into File Storage, then you can visit the file via [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/get-file) within PHP.

You can follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share to mount the file share in your VM.

Additionally, do not forget to enable the 445 outbound rule in firewall in VM and Network Secure Group if you are using the VM in ARM mode.

When successfully, you can get the similar file sys structure like:
[image]

Comment: Thank You so much Gary!! Worked smooth. One question, while creating this network location, it is only seen by me. if the other users of this VM want to dump anything in this network location, how would they do?

Comment: As in this workaround, actually, we are using File Storage, so we can implement functionalities with [File Service REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/file-service-rest-api) to have operations against files in it.

Comment: Hi Gary, as for file storage we can have a network location in our VM, same way for blob storage also can we have a network location? I dont want to manually dump my image files regularly to the blob storage.

Comment: Maybe cou can try to leverage `AzCopy` instead of your custom scripts, refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy#blob-download for more.

Comment: I am very thankfull for ur response yet again. Okay, So you are saying I should schedule AzCopy in the task scheduler in my VM to dump everyday images?

Comment: That's a suggestion.